# Backup SharePoint (2010) documents only

Tags: backup, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I was wondering if it is possible to backup the files itself from SharePoint 2010 from all hosted sites? 
I can backup my entire virtual machine and the database, but i'm only interested in the content itself so that I can access the files itself in case of a failure and not needing to first restore a server/sql server + SharePoint site.

is there such a function in SharePoint itself (or maybe a PowerShell script) that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to export an entire document library with `Export-SPWeb`:

```
$Site = "https://sp.company.net/IntranetSite"
$Library = "https://sp.company.net/IntranetSite/Stuff/ImportantNotes/AllItems.aspx"
$Location = "C:\sharepointbackup\NoteDocuments"
Export-SPWeb -Identity $Site -Path $Location -ItemUrl $Library -NoFileCompression
```

Comment: great, didn't know this was available!